# Have any C compilers ever *defined* `unsigned short x=-3; x*=x;` to yield anything other than 9

Tags: c, history, undefined-behavior

In a C implementation where `int` can hold all values of type `unsigned short`, standard integer promotion rules dictate that given the code:

```
unsigned short x=(USHORT_MAX+1)-3; // Or just -3
x*=x;
```

a compiler should evaluate the latter statement as equivalent to `x=(unsigned short)((int)x * (int)x);`.  Even though unsigned values are nominally supposed to behave according to the rules of modular arithmetic, the standard imposes no requirements upon the behavior of such a statement when `x` exceeds sqrt(INT_MAX), and a compiler could legitimately specify a behavior other than computing a result as if the computation were performed in unsigned fashion in the destination type.  *Has any historical C implementation ever **specified**, in cases where the result of integer operators other than `>>`, `%`, and `/` is coerced to an unsigned type smaller than `int`, a behavior contrary to what would be yielded if the operands were coerced to, and computation were performed in, the destination type*?

On a related note, how many "classical" C compilers have there been which, given code like the above, might plausibly have failed to compute 9?  A two's-complement machine would get that result if it simply ignored any overflow in the multiply, but a sign-magnitude machine which attempted to perform the computation using signed integer math could not.  On the other hand, having compilers look at how an expression will be used when deciding how to evaluate it has been a longstanding practice in many C compilers, and a compiler could easily observe that if arithmetic is being performed on non-negative values and the result is being coerced to unsigned short, the standard would allow unsigned values to be substituted, avoiding any need for sign-handling logic.

Comment: Did this actually happen to you, or is it merely speculative?  If it's defined behavior in the C specification, and the compiler ever produces some result other than the one you illustrated, then the compiler is broken.  That said, if you're referring to math in the general case, the specification *does* allow some variation, depending on the specific definition of the data types in the compiler implementation.

Comment: See also http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Integers.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey: If `int` is 32 bits and `unsigned short` is 16 bits, then because of integer promotion rules the behavior is undefined. The vast majority of compilers will in fact perform the computation according to the rules of modular arithmetic, but some hyper-modern compilers would instead treat code like `x *= x;` as an invitation to infer that in any circumstance where it is reachable, `x` must be less than 46341, and that if the code isn't reachable with `x` less than 46341 it must not be reachable at all.  Such assumptions can severely break code that would otherwise work just fine.

Comment: Yes, that's why I call it a "broken compiler."

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The compiler making such an inference would be conforming to the spec as written. Personally, I think the problem is a broken spec which could and should be fixed by saying the result in such cases must be as if computed with an unsigned type (yielding completely-defined behavior) but it's possible that code might exist somewhere that quite legitimately relies upon a compiler doing something unusual in the aforementioned cases, and specifying the common behavior might forbid a compiler from processing such code in the fashion it requires.

Comment: Did you read the article I linked?  Many compilers provide constants that specify the number of bits in the integer with greater precision, so that you can write code that works properly under all conditions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Those types don't solve the fundamental problem of unsigned types smaller than `int` getting promoted to signed `int`. On a compiler where `int` is 32 bits, `uint16_t` would yield the same problem as `unsigned short`.  Somewhat interestingly, 32-bit platforms, given `int16_t i; uint16_t u;`, are *required* to define the behavior of `i*=i;` for all values of `i`, but are allowed to interpret `u*=u;` any way they like, without having to say how, for `u` values over 46340. The latter expression could be safely written as `u*=1u*u;` but that's ugly.

Comment: There are ways to write code like this that are platform independent and avoid these problems; the spec can already adequately encompass those ways.  The way to do that would be to write your code in such a way that there's no possibility of promotion ever occurring; one obvious way would be to simply avoid the smaller int sizes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The C standard has never defined *any practical means* by which code can use small unsigned types without integer promotion, since even in those cases where integer promotion would be totally useless it was harmless, and there has been no need to prevent it. The only problem is a situation where integer promotion would have no effect on any standard-defined behavior, but causes a behavior that would have been fully defined in the absence of promotion to be exempted from the C specification.

Comment: Then don't use small unsigned types.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I suppose code could read files entirely using `getc()` which returns a byte in each `int`, and thus avoid ever doing anything with `char`, but that's hardly a recipe for performance.  From what I can tell, a nicer solution that would allow more efficient code and save countless programmers a lot of time would be to change the spec to eliminate Undefined Behavior in this particular situation; I'm not 100% sure that change would be compatible with all existing code, though.

Comment: @supercat - Ever? Of course. The mid 1970s to the mid 1990s was the age of the minicomputers. There were lots of minicomputer manufacturers; almost all of them are now gone. Lots of them had lousy compilers, goofy architectures. (For example, middle-endian computers). You didn't overflow, signed or unsigned, in those days if you wanted your code to be portable. Nowadays, a compiler that is not at a **minimum** ISO/IEC 9899:1990-compliant is a completely broken beast from a previous millennium. Even in that 25 year old version of the standard, it's very clear how unsigned integers work.

Comment: @DavidHammen: The main question is whether compilers have ever *defined* a particular behavior other than modular arithmetic.  If a particular compiler's documentation specified that such an expression would yield `42`, then code written for that compiler would be entitled to expect it to yield 42, and any C language specification which would require that compiler to yield 9 instead would break what had been a well-defined (though not strictly-conforming) program.  Are you aware of any compilers that *defined* such behavior?

Comment: @supercat - I do remember that some dropped core at the drop of a hat. I haven't run into a C compiler that doesn't comply with ANSI C (C89/C90) for at 15 or 20 years, so you are asking me to reach way back.

Comment: @DavidHammen: The C Standards Committee has generally been philosophically opposed to mandating any behavior which would be contrary to any behavior *defined* by an existing compiler.  In all cases where the behavior is defined by the standard, expressions of the indicated form would behave as though they were performed using modular arithmetic in the destination base; further, while I'm certainly aware of cases where it would be cheaper to only require `x*=x` to be evaluated mod 65536 when `x` is in the 0..255 range, I know of no practical cases...

Comment: ...where exempting values of `x` in the 46341..65535 range would make things any cheaper.  All that would be required to extend the range would be for a compiler to (1a) not bother performing needless computations on upper bits which are going to get lopped off, or (1b) silently perform such calculations in a way consistent with two's-complement math; and (2) not use such expressions as a basis for inferences about the value of `x`.  Since the analysis necessary to recognize expressions of the indicated form is a tiny subset of that required for fancy inferences...

Comment: ...it should not be difficult for the optimizer to exempt such instructions from inferences; although compilers prone to making such inferences often have an option to make *all* integer calculations wrap, that would be akin to hitting a fly with a sledge-hammer. Making all integers wrap would prevent the compiler from making useful inferences like `x+1>x` for any `int x`. By contrast, the only "inferences" blocked by extending defined behavior to coerced small unsigned types would be ones that would have little practical use anyway.

Comment: @supercat - You are barking up the wrong tree. Early in the days of C, there were lots of compilers that didn't comply with the defacto standard of the time, K&R C. This hindered portability. Every program was sprinkled with `#if (defined THIS_COMPUTER && THIS_COMPUTER) ... #elsif ...` The purpose of a standard is to eliminate some of that nonsense. Even C90 specifies that unsigned integers use modular arithmetic. So long as `k*k` is less than `n+1`, `(((n+1)-k)*((n+1)-k)) % (n+1) == k*k`. It's basic math.

Comment: @DavidHammen: The problem is that if `unsigned short` gets promoted to `int` and the result is cast back to `unsigned short`, the standard presently only mandates modular arithmetic *if no computed value exceeds the range of `int`*.  On a system with 32-bit `int` and 16-bit `unsigned short`, the above calculation would multiply 65533 (0xFFFD) by 65533; because the arithmetic product 4294574089 (or 0xFFFA0009) is not representable as an `int`, the standard presently allows compilers to evaluate it however they want.

Comment: @supercat - I'm done. I strongly suggest you read the standard. If your compiler vendor isn't compliant, get another compiler vendor.

Comment: @DavidHammen: I've read the standard; by my reading, when `USHORT_MAX < INT_MAX`, `x*=x;` is required to be interpreted as `x=(unsigned short)((int)x*(int)x);`, the latter subexpression `((int)x*(int)x);` will trigger Undefined Behavior if the product won't fit in `int`, and such Undefined Behavior completely exempts the compiler from meeting any other requirements.  Can you point me to anything in the standard that would forbid a 100%-compliant compiler from regarding the expression as invoking Undefined Behavior and using that to justify whatever it wants?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23474/discussion-on-question-by-supercat-have-any-c-compilers-ever-defined-unsigned).